# How do I stop all tabs becoming pinned in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been trying to use the vs code pinned tabs feature as I have a few files that I use regularly so it would save me time. Problem is, it doesn't really work as once I've pinned one tab, every one I then select becomes pinned. The only way to stop the behaviour is to unpin everything but then I'm back to square one. I would expect the pinned tabs to stay there and to be able to navigate the rest of the files as normal. I must be missing something but is there a setting somewhere to enable this behaviour? The feature seems utterly pointless otherwise.

Pinning the tabs I want pinned (works fine). And then viewing unpinned files but doing that pins them too

Comment: I can't replicate this in Stable or Insiders.  Does it still happen if you reload with all extensions disabled (there is a command that does that in the Command Palette?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour was being caused by the [`kylepaulsen.stack-tabs`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kylepaulsen.stack-tabs) extension. You technically have the option of disabling that extension to make this stop.

If in the future you want to figure out if a certain behaviour is caused by an extension, follow this procedure: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.